# curlでのHTTP post を ruby に書き換えで失敗する

Tags: ruby, api, dropbox

DropboxにAPI2を使いファイルのアップロードをしたいので下記の`curl`コマンドでファイルが正常にアップロードされるのを確認しました。

```
curl -X POST https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer $access_token" \
    --header "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
    --header "Dropbox-API-Arg: {\"path\": \"test.txt\", \"mode\": \"overwrite\"}" \
--data-binary @foo.txt
```

これをRubyのコードにおき変えるために

```
access_token = ENV['DROPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN']
uri = URI.parse('https://content.dropboxapi.com')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("2/files/upload")
request.add_field('Authorization', "Bearer #{access_token}")
request.add_field('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
request.add_field('Dropbox-API-Arg', {path: '/test.txt', mode: 'overwrite'})
request.body = File.read('foo.txt')
http.request(request)
```

としたのですが `#<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>`になってしまいました。

`400`エラーだけでは原因をどのように特定していけばよいのかわからないのですが、このような場合どのようにエラーを取り除けば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: 参考情報: [rubyで動画などの大きなファイルをアップロードする場合のメモリの使い方について](http://qiita.com/asukamirai/items/c950c65c6473ca8ca96c)

Comment: 大きなファイルをアップロードする場合は必要になりそうですね、情報ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

レスポンスボディを見るのが手がかりになると思います。

```
res = http.request(request)
p res.body
```

最後の一行を上記のように修正すると、どのようなレスポンスが返ってくるのかわかると思います。

ちなみに、
`request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("2/files/upload")`
は
`request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/2/files/upload")`
だと思うので一緒に修正してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。 指摘いただいたPostのパスの追加をして確認すると"Error in call to API function \"files/upload\": HTTP header \"Dropbox-API-Arg\": could not decode input as JSON"のエラーだったので `Dropbox-API-Arg` の値を`%q({"path": "/test.txt", "mode": "overwrite"}))`とJSONを渡してやると正常にアップロードできました。てっきり`Hash`を渡すのだと勘違いしていたのが原因でした。