# curlコマンドのrubyで実装について

Tags: ruby, curl

下記のcurlの内容をrubyで実現しようとしているのですが
400エラーなどが出てうまくいきません。

`curl -F grant_type=refresh_token -F refresh_token=<refresh token> client_id=<client id> -F client_secret=<client secret> -X POST https://test/token`

rubyでcurlの-Fオプションを実装する場合どのように記述すればよろしいのでしょうか?
お手数ですが、回答の程よろしくお願い致します。

2018/04/18追記
cubick様、nekketsuuu様

コメントありがとうございます。
申し訳ございません、実装してみたコードやエラーなどを記載しておらず、
質問の内容がよくありませんでした。

下記にコードとエラーを記載させていただきます。

■コード

```
def updateAccessToken()
    json = ''
    uri = URI.parse("http://test/token")
    Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port){|http|
      request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
      request.set_form_data('grant_type' => 'refresh_token')
      request.set_form_data('refresh_token' => 'dfafdasfdasdfadsfsa3')
      request.set_form_data('client_id' => '2121fdasgadsraea')
      request.set_form_data('client_secret' => '2121fdasgadsraea')
      json = http.request(request)
    }
    return json
end
```

■エラー

```
Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true
```

kunif様

コメントありがとうございます。
紹介していただいたサイトも試してみましたが上に記載したエラー内容が出てしまい、
同じ結果でした。

2018/04/23追記
kunif様

コメントありがとうございます。
紹介していただいたリンク先の方法で調査を行ってみようかと思います。
何度も対応していただきありがとうございました。

Comment: 邪道かもしれませんが、こんなサイト[curl-to-ruby](https://jhawthorn.github.io/curl-to-ruby/)があるようです。古いですが[体験・紹介の記事](http://www.softantenna.com/wp/webservice/curl-to-ruby/)があります。

Comment: 付いた回答で解決するかもしれませんが、この質問記事ページの右側にある「関連する質問」の[curlでのHTTP post を ruby に書き換えで失敗する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/18641/curl%e3%81%a7%e3%81%aehttp-post-%e3%82%92-ruby-%e3%81%ab%e6%9b%b8%e3%81%8d%e6%8f%9b%e3%81%88%e3%81%a7%e5%a4%b1%e6%95%97%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b?rq=1)の回答に、レスポンスボディを見るのが手掛かりになるとありますので、試してみては？

Answer (score 3):

`400 Bad Request` が出るということはリクエスト内容がサーバーの期待するものではないということだと思います。

curl の -F は `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` のリクエストを発行しますが、Ruby の `Net::HTTP::Post` は `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` のリクエストを発行するので、そのせいかもしれません。

Ruby で `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` リクエストを発行したい場合は、`set_form_data` ではなく `set_form` を使用するのが良いと思います。

次のページが参考になると思います。
http://masamitsu-murase.blogspot.jp/2017/01/ruby-nethttp-multipart-post.html